# Is this right? Trig integration $\int \sec^3 (x)\tan^2 (x)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

$$\begin{align}
\int\sec^3(x)\tan^2(x)\,dx&=\int\sec^3(x)(\sec^2(x)-1)\,dx \\
&=\int\sec^5(x)\,dx-\int\sec^3(x)\,dx
\end{align}$$

$$\int\sec^3(x)\,dx=\frac12(\sec(x)\tan(x)+\ln|\sec(x)+\tan(x)|)+C$$

---

$$\int\sec^5(x)\,dx$$ Let $u=\sec^3(x)$, then $du=3\sec^3(x)\tan(x)\,dx $. Let $dv=\sec^2(x)\,dx$, then $v=\tan(x)$

$$\begin{align}
\int\sec^5(x)\,dx&=\sec^3(x)\tan(x)-3\int\sec^3(x)(\sec^2(x)-1)\,dx \\
&=\sec^3(x)\tan(x)-3\int\sec^5(x)\,dx+3\int\sec^3(x)\,dx \\
&=\frac14\sec^3(x)\tan(x)+\frac38(\sec(x)\tan(x)+\ln|\sec(x)+\tan(x)|)+C
\end{align}$$

$$\int\sec^5(x)\,dx-\int\sec^3(x)\,dx=\frac14\sec^3(x)\tan(x)-\frac18(\sec(x)\tan(x)+\ln|\sec(x)+\tan(x)|)+C$$

Comment: Nice work, your answer and all the steps are correct. Next time, you can check your answer here (http://www.integral-calculator.com)

Comment: That website has a check option? Sometimes they get the answer a different way and our answers look different but equivalent.

Comment: Yes you are right, so sometimes you could only check your final answer on that website.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your comment. Indeed, we have to change our answers into other equivalent forms sometimes, especially for integral involving trig functions. But this time is quite lucky as the website output exactly the same steps as yours.

Comment: @MengchunZhang Could you please post your comment as an answer so this question can be removed from the "Unanswered" queue?

Comment: @user349557 One other way to check if two different solutions are equal, no matter which website you use, is to graph both of them and see if the graphs are the same! Desmos (https://www.desmos.com/calculator) is pretty great for that sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, everything's correct here!